# How to read parquet files in chunk wise?

Tags: pandas, parquet

I have a parquet file which is having a size of 350 GB. therefore I want to read the data in chunk.

I am aware of reading full parquet file and then convert them to pandas as below.

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table(filepath)
df = table.to_pandas(integer_object_nulls=True)
```

Not sure whether it is possible to read data chunk by chunk. Can someone please clarify on this!

Comment: Have you considered using [dask](https://dask.org/)? Pandas doesn't have the option to read by chunk.

Comment: I need to use already developed framework to add some extra columns(this uses pandas).
I do not have much idea on dask. is it possible to read data in chunk wise in dask and then convert to pandas , so I can use my other python code to add new fields

Comment: You can read the big parquet file with dask and save in many smaller parquet or use basically all your code to add new columns. If you can produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) I can try to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to read parquet files in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098785/is-it-possible-to-read-parquet-files-in-chunks)