# How to read parquet file and create chunk to process?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet, chunks

I have a large parquet file that I can read into a pandas dataframe with read_parquet(). However, I wanted to process the file chunk by chunk and then create the processed dataframe. Is there any way I wan achieve this? read_csv with chunk size is not an option for my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098785/is-it-possible-to-read-parquet-files-in-chunks

Comment: Look at Iteration from fastparquet Python lib: https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#iteration